# How to create method for withdrawal from store and deliverance to store

Tags: java

I am studying java by myself and I want to get help on exercise which i am doing myself. 
The class is called Product which used for representing a product that a small company sells.

It should be possible to store the following information about each product.
The class should have the following methods:

- A constructor
- A method that returns the units of items in store
- A method for deliverance to the store (increases the units of this product)
- A method for withdrawal from the store (decreases the units of this product)

Please note that if one of the methods changes the stored items below the order point a message should be printed. It should also be impossible to have a negative amount of items.

I HAVE PROBLEM WITH METHODS. PLEASE TAKE A LOOK MY CODE AND GIVE ME SOME HINTS. I WILL APPRECIATE ALL RESPONDS. 
THANK YOU.

Here is my program:

```
  public class Product {
        private int productNumber;
        private String productName;
        private float price;
        private int orderPoint;
        private int unitsInStore;
        private String proDescription;

        public Product(int num, String name, float price, int order, int units, String description){
            this.productNumber = num;
            this.productName = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.orderPoint = order;
            this.unitsInStore = units;
            this.proDescription = description;
        }

        public int getProductNumber() {
            return productNumber;
        }

        public void setProductNumber(int productNumber) {
            this.productNumber = productNumber;
        }

        public String getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }

        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }

        public float getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(float price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public int getOrderPoint() {
            return orderPoint;
        }

        public void setOrderPoint(int orderPoint) {
            this.orderPoint = orderPoint;
        }

        // a method returns the units in store
        public int getUnitsInStore() {
            return unitsInStore;
        }

        public void setUnitsInStore(int unitsInStore) {
            this.unitsInStore = unitsInStore;
        }

        public String getProDescription() {
            return proDescription;
        }

        public void setProDescription(String proDescription) {
            this.proDescription = proDescription;
        }

        public int deliveranceToStore(int store){
          unitsInStore = unitsInStore + store;
         return unitsInStore ++ ;
}
       public int withdrawal(int store){
        unitsInStore = store - unitsInStore;
return unitsInStore --;
}
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem with methods?

Comment: Why not simply create methods that do that for you. ? Are you unfamiliar with methods in Java. ?

Comment: Yes I am not good at creating methods, that is my problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deliveranceToStore` method isn't correct. Why are you calling the method recursively?

The method can simply be:

```
public int deliveranceToStore(int store) {
    unitsInStore = unitsInStore + store;
    return unitsInStore;
}
```

If there is no need to return the number of units in store with this call, you should have the return type as `void` (i.e., if updating the count is sufficient):

```
public void deliveranceToStore(int store) {
    unitsInStore = unitsInStore + store;
}
```

For withdrawal, you need a similar strategy where `unitsInStore` is updated:

```
public void withdrawal(int units) {
    if(unitsInStore - units >= 0) {
        unitsInStore = unitsInStore - units;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to withdraw. Insufficient units in store.");
    }
}
```

You can also make the `withdrawal` method return a `boolean` which tells whether the withdrawal action was successful. The method, in that case, may look like:

```
public boolean withdrawal(int units) {
    if(unitsInStore - units >= 0) {
        unitsInStore = unitsInStore - units;
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unable to withdraw. Insufficient units in store.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. if i want to create method for withdrawal from store. Is it right? I felt like I am doing something wrong. Can you check it for me.

Comment: 'public int withdrawal(int store){
 return store - unitsInStore;
}'

Comment: How can I learn java more sufficient ? Can give me some suggestions?

Comment: @BraveSatisfaction The official tutorial is a good place to begin with - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial